# Bluetooth connection fails by connecting to the Logitech MX Master S2 mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, bluez

I am using Linux Mint 18.2 Sonja and want to connect my new **Logitech MX Master S2 mouse** without using the bluetooth-dongle, but directly with the inbuilt bluetooth module of my notebook. This works so far with my PC after running the commands:

```
~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1
~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 down
~$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up
```

However by entering `sudo hciconfig hci0 sspmode 1` I get the following error message on my notebook:

```
Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Input/output error (5)
```

After reading a few articles in different communities they recommended to do the following:

```
alpha@Pavilion ~ $ bluetoothctl 
[NEW] Controller B0:35:9F:0E:4F:3D Pavilion [default]
[NEW] Device C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D MX Master 2S
[NEW] Device DD:6A:F3:5A:A2:A2 MI Band 2
[NEW] Device C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3B MX Master 2S
[NEW] Device 00:02:3C:51:C6:12 Creative T50 Wireless
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent 
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Device C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D RSSI: -15
[bluetooth]# scan off
Discovery stopped
[CHG] Device C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D RSSI: -4
[bluetooth]# trust C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D
Changing C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D trust succeeded
[bluetooth]# pair C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D
Attempting to pair with C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D
[CHG] Device C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationTimeout
[CHG] Device C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D Connected: no
[bluetooth]# connect C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D
Attempting to connect to C5:E2:3F:77:5C:3D
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]# version
Version 5.37
[bluetooth]# exit
Agent unregistered
[DEL] Controller B0:35:9F:0E:4F:3D Pavilion [default]
alpha@Pavilion ~ $
```

As you can see, by trying to pair the mouse it is shortly connected and followed by the error: `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationTimeout`
Has someone an idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least I found a way to solve the problem:
I installed the **Bluetooth Manager** called blueman:

```
~$ sudo apt install blueman
```

In the GUI there is a button which looks like a calculator or so, called "Create pairing with the device" when you hover over it. While by right-click neither the buttons "pair" nor "Setup / pair device" work, the mentioned button above did the job!

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`:

```
ControllerMode = dual
```

Did the trick for me.

Credit to this [post](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/logitech-mx-master-2s-not-connecting-over-bluetooth/59765)

Comment: `dual` was already the default. I still get "Can't set Simple Pairing mode on hci0: Input/output error (5)"

Comment: Same here. `dual` is the default value, but had to be set explicitly to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I got to stop scan on the original OP.
I couldn't CGH... I didn't know what to do so I keyed in

```
[bluetooth]# pair
```

and got

```
Missing device address argument
```

Then I added my device address (which wasn't recognised in the scan)

```
[bluetooth]# pair D7:OE:48:E9:1F;E1
```

Then it connected as below

```
[CHG] Device D7:0E:48:E9:1F:E1 Connected: yes
```

Then showed the pass key and I typed that into the keyboard and hit enter.

```
[agent] Passkey: 743005
```

I'm now typing this on MX Keys in Kali Linux.

Thanks for the starter and as an aside I had blueman installed.