# pulseaudio does not start

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

System: Linux Mint Cinnamon 18.2 Sonja

After I had some struggle to connect my bluetooth mouse with my notebook
[(see here)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430196/bluetooth-connection-fails-by-connecting-to-the-logitech-mx-master-s2-mouse/430208#430208),
the system does not recognize any sound devices. Neither my inbuilt loudspeaker nor my inbuilt microphone will be shown in "start / system_settings / hardware / sound / output | input".  The sound-applet in the panel (task-bar) also will not be shown.

I already reinstalled pulseaudio, still it gives me following error back:

```
alpha@Pavilion ~ $ pulseaudio 
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Unknown command: module-bluetooth-policy
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
alpha@Pavilion ~ $ pulseaudio --start
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Daemon startup failed.
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix pulseaudio?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i had a same issue, but i solved much easier:  `pulseaudio --start`, `pulseaudio -k`, `pulseaudio` (got some errors but all fine), `pulseaudio --start`  all worked !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like i messed it up by myself. Luckily I found the problem:
As i mentioned before I had some struggle to connect my bluetooth mouse, so I made a couple of changes. Unfortunately I forgot to remove the previously inserted lines in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, which were the following:

```
module-bluetooth-policy
module-bluez5-device
module-bluez5-discover
```

Aftere removing those lines and executing the following commands everything works fine again.

```
~$ sudo vim /etc/pulse/default.pa 
~$ ## remove the mentioned lines
~$ cd $HOME
~$ mkdir .pulse
~$ pulseaudio --kill
~$ pulseaudio --start
~$ sudo reboot now
```

Comment: this somehow solved my problem, i can hear audio now whenevr i change the sound bar on pavucontrol but I can't hear anything from my browsers.